# How do I use a variable from Python input in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want the SQL term to search for the ID that has been given by the user as input.

```
def autoAusgeben():

    autoID = int(input("Id des Autos eingeben: "))
    connection = sqlite3.connect("quartett.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * From autos WHERE Id (?)", (autoID))
    autos = cursor.fetchall()
    print(autos)
```

Comment: Presumably what you've posted _doesn't_ work - errors? Unexpected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

If autoID is defined earlier in code, then I believe you may be receiving some kind of "undefined function 'Id' in expression error" due to missing = sign? Does changing that line to this help?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * From autos WHERE Id = (?)", (autoID))
```

Comment: The second argument to `execute` is also missing the `,` that makes it the required tuple.

Answer (score 0):

After adding to missing "=" it gives the error "parameters are of unsopported type".
autoID has never been used before.

EDIT:
ive added a "," behind autoID in braces

Works now

Thx